# .load jquery not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

I'm working on a project and I keep running in this particular problem that .load won't work in Google Chrome. Here's the javascript:

```
    function link1() {
     $('#loadarea').html('loading.....');
      setTimeout('link1_go()', 850);
    }
    function link1_go() {
      $('#loadarea').load("regular.html");
      $('#loadarea').hide().fadeIn('slow');
    }
```

And here's the clickable div to call the action:

```
<div id="link1" class="clickableload" onclick="link1()">
```

And then there's the container to load it in:

```
<div id="loadarea"></div>
```

It's working firefox and ie but not in chrome. Any suggestions guys?

Comment: Are you getting any js errors?  What does the network tab show you (any request being made?)

Comment: What happens if you comment out the hide/fade and bypass the timeout to just call `.load()` directly? (Just trying to help narrow down the problem.)

Comment: Don't pass strings into `setTimeout`, it's just a bad idea. Instead, always pass a function reference (in this case, `setTimeout(link1_go, 850);` as @Jacob points out).

Comment: What's the error message you're getting? Saying it doesn't work is not enough info.

Comment: ***How*** is it not working in Chrome? What does it do? What do you *expect* it to do?

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your `setTimeout` call.  When you use a string parameter for `setTimeout`, that invokes a browser's `eval` function, which might not do what you expect, especially if `link1_go` isn't a global function.  Do this instead:

```
setTimeout(link1_go, 850);
```

Comment: Variable scoping is one thing that behaves radically different across browsers.  See this fantastic article: http://blog.rakeshpai.me/2008/10/understanding-eval-scope-spoiler-its.html

Answer (score 0):

I have, lately, being very carefull when it comes to "sequence-of-events". Whenever possible, I make sure the statements are only loaded in the sequence I want. I have had no troubles in Chrome which is my primary debugging web browser.

For the case shown, I would suggest the following fix:

```
function link1() {
    $('#loadarea').html( function () {
        setTimeout('link1_go()', 850);
        return '<p>loading.....</p>';
    })
}

function link1_go() {
    $('#loadarea').fadeOut().load("regular.html").fadeIn('slow');
}

Since the "loadarea" is already displaying "loading ... "; a fadeout and a fadein would be more elegant then hide() and fadeIn.

Furthermore, for the present request, I would get away with link1_go completely:

function link1() {
    $('#loadarea').html( function () {
        setTimeout("$('#loadarea').fadeOut().load('regular.html').fadeIn('slow')", 850);
        return '<p>loading.....</p>';
    })
}
```

Comment: I appreciate all the input. I found out the problem. It seems that it will work when I've tried it with localhost. I was opening the html document locally (anywhere but the htdocs or www folder) and it wasn't working. But it did work when I simulated it with xampserver.